# t-sql counting unique words in text column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column which contains captions to images. What I want to do is find the most popular words occurring in that column.

Is there a way to do this with t-sql?

Comment: Especially in T-SQL? Standard SQL does not suffice?

Comment: Maybe this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco) is a starting point? From there you can split your column contents and then maybe group?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MS SQL 2008?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this.   I don't think this is the most optimized, but you can improve on it.

Create a table variable @t to store the words
Create a cursor, loop through each row in your captions table.
for each row, use the chunk split function to get a table (http://www.sommarskog.se/arraylist-2005/tblnum-functions.html#chunk_split_me)
add the words from the table to the table variable @t

Do a word and count(word) and order descending on @t .

Comment: I surgest you read up on Igor's post. The link you gave is not really useful.

Comment: Thanks.  Like I said, it's just a starting point.  Thanks for the help.